# Node.js clustering with socket.io and mysql sessionstore

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing, socket.io-redis

I'm trying to cluster a node app that runs with mysql, mysql session store and massive usage of socket.io.
I was looking for a way to adapt the socket.io session storage in mysql but i only found some redis adapter (following this guidelines : https://github.com/elad/node-cluster-socket.io)

Is there a way to implement node clustering with socket.io and mysql without installing redis ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-mysql-session If it does not satisfy you, you will have to make your own socket.io session manager.This will not take more than 2-3 hours. I believe mysql is not exactly what you want to use to store socket.io data as a user is lost in every refresh meaning that a caching mechanism like redis is a better choice to use overall